# Result of parsing date is wrong by 16 hours 2 minutes

Tags: java, date, parsing

I have a string `07/Dec/2016:07:38:59 1000`.
I want to parse it to a date.
What do I do to become a date `07/Dec/2016 07:38:59 1000` as a result?
Now it prints out `Wed Dec 07 23:40:59 CET 2016`.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimeParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String time ="07/Dec/2016:07:38:59 1000";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss");

        String dateString = format.format( new Date()   );
        Date   date       = format.parse ( "07/Dec/2016:07:38:59 1000" );

        System.out.println(date);

    }
}
```

Comment: Well you've got an extra ` 1000` at the end of your string. What's that meant to be for? You're also using 12-hour parsing (`hh`) when I strongly suspect you want 24 hour parsing (`HH`).

Comment: what is `tet` means ?

Comment: the extra 1000  is in the String.

Comment: what does the 1000 mean? millisecond timezone, what exactly ?

Comment: On my computer your program prints `Wed Dec 07 07:38:59 CET 2016`, which seems to be the result you expected. I have no idea why the result is 16 hours 2 minutes wrong on your computer. Sorry.

Comment: Can you reboot your computer and get the same result again? I cannot explain how it would help, but it’s my best suggestion for something to try.

Comment: The other — and maybe really better — suggestion is you switch to using the Java 8 date and time classes. They are in the `java.time` package and are generally much more convenient to work with than `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` and seldom give surprises.

Comment: My guess it the 1000 is a time zone offset indicator, +10:00. Just a guess, though. If the asker doesn’t know, nobody here knows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the 1000 is supposed to be milliseconds? if so, it's incorrect. it's like writing 13:60:60

This also means the time string format you entered is missing the milliseconds value.
It should be `"dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss SSS"`
milliseconds value should not be more than 3 digits