# Convert String to Date and time in java

Tags: java, date, time

My program reading data from a database and I want to convert some fields to date format (date and time separately). I can do this from sql query but is it possible to do from java code.

date format in table = **MMDDHHMISS** (month day hour minute sec)

and these are sql queries now I'm using-

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATETIMECOLUMN, 'MMDDHH24MISS'),'DD/MM/YYYY') AS MY_DATE

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATETIMECOLUMN, 'MMDDHH24MISS'),'HH24:MI:SS') AS MY_TIME
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/5613292

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: I went trough above answers but couldn't find a way to convert my kind of String to date time

Comment: This has been asked and answered several time before. Please search harder.

Comment: The best you can do is to avoid converting your database date-time to string and back. Better to get for example `LocalDateTime` objects directly from your result set.

Comment: Sorry about the off-StackOverflow link, it’s in here if you scroll down to it: [Convert Java Date/Time to String & String back to Date/Time](https://www.java-success.com/convert-java-date-to-string-string-back-to-date/).

Comment: Please see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38561397/5772882) for how to get `LocalDateTime` objects from your result set.

Comment: Should your resulting date include a year? If so, how to decide which year? Java does offer the `MonthDay` class for dates without a year, in case that fulfils your requirements.

Comment: Please see these questions: (1) [Java - How to check if a value is of type Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631718/java-how-to-check-if-a-value-is-of-type-date). (2) [Android converting date time parse error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487282/android-converting-date-time-parse-error-even-tried-joda-time) (3) [Result of parsing date is wrong by 16 hours 2 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884951/result-of-parsing-date-is-wrong-by-16-hours-2-minutes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a suggestion:

```
    DateTimeFormatter databaseStringFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddHHmmss"); 
    String sampleDatabaseString = "1129225145";
    MonthDay myDate = MonthDay.parse(sampleDatabaseString, databaseStringFormatter);
    LocalTime myTime = LocalTime.parse(sampleDatabaseString, databaseStringFormatter);
    System.out.println("Date: " + myDate + ". Time: " + myTime + '.');
```

The above prints

```
Date: --11-29. Time: 22:51:45.
```

`MonthDay` is a date without a year, useful for birthdays and other anniversary dates.

Unless there are specific reasons to avoid it, I think you should rather change the datatype of your database column to `datetime` or similar and then retrieve `LocalDateTime` objects from your result set as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38561397/5772882). This would free you from any conversion from string to date and time in either the database query or in Java.